auto_date_histogram exceeding the time filter range giving in the search query in elastic search
     `{
  query: {
    bool: {
      must: [
        {
          query_string: {
            query: "_index : (*)",
            analyze_wildcard: true,
            default_field: "*",
            allow_leading_wildcard: true,
            default_operator: "AND",
          },
        },
      ],
      filter: [
        {
          range: {
            "@timestamp": {
              gte: "2024-03-31T18:30:00.000Z",
              lte: "2024-04-11T18:29:00.000Z",
            },
          },`your text`
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  size: 0,
  from: 0,
  sort: [{ "@timestamp": { order: "desc" } }],
  aggs: {
    "@timestamp": {
      auto_date_histogram: { field: "@timestamp", buckets: 100 },
      aggs: {},
    },
  },
}`


this is the ES query that i am using with nodejs, i am getting result which is exceeding the time range that i gave in the query..
how can we solve this issue, or else this is the behaviour of auto_date_histogram in ES as ES deciding interval and bucket size in auto_date_histogram query
i wanted to get the result in the specified time range

because the query is not correct, you have extra commas, fix it then run it
